# How to filter ItemGroup in MsBuild based on filename part?

Tags: msbuild

I have an `ItemGroup` that contains some files (And I have no control on how this list is generated):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AllFiles Include="Assembly1.dll;Assembly1.Tests.dll"/>
    <AllFiles Include="Assembly2.dll;Assembly2.Tests.dll"/>
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

And I would like to create a second `ItemGroup` (based on the first one) holding only for filenames matching `****.Tests.dll`. That is `FilteredFiles` should be: `Assembly1.Tests.dll`, `Assembly2.Tests.dll`, ...

So far I tried:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FilteredFiles Include="@(AllFiles)" Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch(%(Filename), '\.Tests\.dll'))"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

PS: I would also like for non case sensitive matches but that's another issue.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I had forgot for the `@` in the `Include` attribute of my own script... Dreaming for an easier way to debug msbuild scripts ... oO

Comment: You can via a hidden feature.  Not sure if enabled in VS 2012 though.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use item batching using the % instead of the @.  This will work on the items one by one instead of including them all at the same time.  You had the condition right, which I assume you found somewhere else.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FilteredFiles Include="%(AllFiles.Identity)" Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch(%(Filename), '\.Tests\.dll'))"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Correcting `Include="(AllFiles)"` with `Include="@(AllFiles)"` was fine enough for the situation ... Anyway, I'll review the script for what you said regarding item batching. Thanks for your support :)