# Link dll's to project depending on platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a folder called 'libs' which contains DLLs. The main project (C#) contains these dlls as links. I would like to ask, is it possible to link libraries to a project when I click build? How about using pre/post-build event? I'd like to link the libs depending on platform too. So if I build debug, I want to use the debug version of dlls, and when I build release version, use release dlls.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by `contains these dlls as link`?

Comment: @sevatitov I assume the OP means when you `Add an existing item` to a project you have the option to `Add as Link`

Comment: Adding these DLLs as links certainly does not help you get this right.  So don't, use xcopy.exe in a post-build event instead.

Comment: Yes I mean Add as Link. But when I build for ARM platform I cannot use xcopy, because the dll's are in package.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to link libraries to a project when I click build? How
>   about using pre/post-build event? I'd like to link the libs depending
>   on platform too. So if I build debug, I want to use the debug version
>   of dlls,

We could use msbuild condition to use different Dlls. Please right click the project-> unload project -> right click the project -> edit xxx.csproj then add the following code like below:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="start $(Platform)" />
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM'">
      <Content Include="..\Libs\Arm\ClassLibrary1.dll">
        <Link>ClassLibrary1.dll</Link>
      </Content>
      <Content Include="..\Libs\Arm\ClassLibrary2.dll">
        <Link>ClassLibrary2.dll</Link>
      </Content>
      <!-- ... other dlls -->
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|ARM'">
      <Content Include="..\Libs\Arm\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll">
        <Link>ClassLibrary1.dll</Link>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: many thanks for answer. And is it possible to use only some dll's from directory? So I mean: use all dll's except these two.

Comment: If you want to add other dlls, please add more content. and modify the reply for your reference.

Comment: Do you resolve your issue? if the issue still exists, could you please provide a bit more information, if the issue resolves, could you please mark the helpful reply as answer, it will be beneficial to other communities.

Comment: Still not. I don't want to write all dll's. I need use regular expression, which dll's should be included and which excluded.

Comment: If you want to use regular expression, it seems that the following thread if helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656811/how-to-filter-itemgroup-in-msbuild-based-on-filename-part