# MSBuild: Filtering Items based on a part of the file path

Tags: msbuild

I have a set of files I need to copy that are underneath a folder that contains the version of the package that deposited those files:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyFiles Include="$(MyPackages)\foo.x64*\binaries\*.*"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

`foo.x64*` can resolve to more than one folder like `foo.x64.17.5.50` and `foo.x64.17.6.2` where the suffix represents the version of package. I want to filter my items based on that version but I can't seem to find a way to extract any part of the item file path as metadata on my item to then use it in batching or conditionals.

Comment: You don't really need to extract a part, you can use conditions on the full path? E.g. `<Message Text="%(MyFiles.Identity)" Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('%(Identity)').Contains('17.5.50'))" />` Anyway I'm pretty sure this has been asked here before. Search for 'msbuild item filter' or so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter ItemGroup in MsBuild based on filename part?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656811/how-to-filter-itemgroup-in-msbuild-based-on-filename-part)

Comment: What exactly do you need to filter? version ranges / filter from items / into new items? or excluding a version from `MyFiles`?

Comment: @MartinUllrich excluding non-latest version would be a great start, though in the future we may want to extend this to exclude all but a specific version as specified by some property set in the .csproj.

Comment: @stijn my problem is different in that I don't know what these version suffixes will be in advance, so hard coding `17.5.50` isn't acceptable. That is why extraction was important. Your conditional is exactly correct, if only the `Contains` could reference a property but I don't know how to set the property!

Comment: Extraction should then be done using regexes, as Martin's answer shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few features of msbuild that can be used here. those are:

1. Defining custom item metadata. let's call them`FooArch` and `FooVersion`
2. MSBuild allows calling some .net APIs including regular expressions. So we can use `RegEx.Match()` here to extract the information you need to know.
3. When doing numeric comparison on strings, MSBuild parses them into Versions. This will allow you to do range conditions like `'%(FooItems.FooVersion)' &lt; '17.6.2'`.

What's not possible out of the box is determining the highest version of a list of items. To achieve this, you'll need to write a custom msbuild task.

A more concrete example: To add the required metadata on the items and copy the right version and architecture, you can do the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <FooRegEx>[\\/]foo\.(?&lt;arch&gt;x(\d*))\.(?&lt;version&gt;((\d+)(\.\d+)+))</FooRegEx>
  <FooVersionToUse>17.5.50</FooVersionToUse>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <FooFiles Include="mypkgs\foo*\binaries\**\*">
    <FooArch>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(%(Identity), $(FooRegEx)).get_Groups().get_Item("arch"))</FooArch>
    <FooVersion>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(%(Identity), $(FooRegEx)).get_Groups().get_Item("version"))</FooVersion>
  </FooFiles>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="IncludeFoo" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FooArchToUse Condition="'$(FooArchToUse)' == '' and '$(Platform)' != 'AnyCPU'">$(Platform)</FooArchToUse>
    <FooArchToUse Condition="'$(FooArchToUse)' == ''">x64</FooArchToUse>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="@(FooFiles)" 
             Link="foo\%(Filename)%(Extension)"
             CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"
             Condition="'%(FooFiles.FooVersion)' == '$(FooVersionToUse)' and '%(FooFiles.FooArch)' == '$(FooArchToUse)'"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

This will copy the items of the selected version and platform built for (defaulting to x64) into a `foo` subfolder of the output directory. (Tested on MSBuild 15.1). I've uploaded the example project to GitHub [here](https://github.com/dasMulli/msbuild-metadata-filter-example).

Comment: Thanks Martin, that regex trick is just the thing I was missing. I did end up writing a custom task to find the latest version, which is unfortunate, but with inline tasks that isn't so painful.

Answer (score 1):

You can you use the ItemGroup's **Condition** Attribute to filter out elements based on some boolean expression. You can use regex for instance as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62710603/3118437).